# How to interpret bootstraping output

Tags: r, normal-distribution, bootstrap, resampling

I have a small dataset which has just 8 elements. I thought I could bootstrap to compare my sample with a normal distribution. I simply want to answer the question: how likely is it that the sample is coming from a normal distribution? Is it correct to use bootstrapping to try to answer this question?

The next one is, I used R to calculate it with `mean` as the function How can I interpret the output?

```
vvD <- c(0.09981546, 0.07528535, 3.35832662, 0.28121880, 
         0.24241056, 0.31650442, 0.21476853, 0.33125265 )
library(boot) # load the package
boot.mean  <- function(x, i){ boot.mean <- mean(x[i]) }
bootobject <- boot(data=vvD, statistic=boot.mean, R=100000) 

Bootstrap Statistics :
    original          bias  std. error
t1*  0.94119 -0.0002207164    0.682218
```

Comment: Although asked in terms of R, this question seems to be about the ideas behind bootstrapping, not about how to use R.

Comment: @gung:thanks, ok where can I ask it?

Comment: My comment was directed to others who might vote to close your Q. I was saying that I think your Q is on-topic here.

Comment: Can you post your 8 values? In your code, you only list "`dataset`".

Comment: sure
vvD<-c(0.09981546, 0.07528535, 3.35832662, 0.28121880, 0.24241056, 0.31650442, 0.21476853, 0.33125265)